# How is the app-location element {{route}} set?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm reading through the code for the [`app-location`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-route/blob/master/app-location.html) element and trying to understand how the `route` property is set.  Does the `app-location` module set this property and how does it go about doing it?

TIA,
Ole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a bit convoluted.  `app-location` itself uses `iron-location` and `iron-query-parameters` window.location.pathname and querystring and the associated pushstate events and with data-binding exposes the path.

`app-location` imports `app-route-converter-behaviour` and it this that produces the `route` object from the path